# why do cocoa arrays add quotes sometimes and not others

Tags: json, cocoa, nsdictionary

Using the following string:

```
"records": [
    {
        "record_id": "REC000000000000009",
        "name": "test 1",
        "email": "test@test.com"
    },
    {
        "record_id": "REC00000000000000A",
        "name": "test race #2",
        "email": "test@test.com"
    }
]
```

When I run it through the following logic only the "record_id" key has quotes.  Also, only the "record_id" value does not have quotes.

```
NSData *httpData = [results dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSError* error;
NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization
                      JSONObjectWithData:httpData
                      options:0
                      error:&error];
```

The result:

records: (
        {
        email = "test@test.com";
        name = "test 1";
        "record_id" = REC000000000000009;
    },
        {
        email = "test@test.com";
        name = "test race #2";
        "record_id" = REC00000000000000A;
    }
)

Any help understanding why this is happening is appreciated.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This just happens to be how `- [NSDictionary description]` formats the dictionary keys (and values). (In particular, this is the legacy NextStep property list format.) This format doesn't demand that strings without punctuation be quoted.

(Of course, neither the keys or values have actual quotes in them.)